# Djoser 'users/me' endpoint only shows login_field and user_id field

Tags: django, rest, django-rest-framework, django-rest-framework-simplejwt, djoser

I want that upon hitting the 'users/me' endpoint, I should get something like

```
{
        "id": 10,
        "email": "test17@test.com",
        "first_name": "test",
        "last_name": null,
        "is_writer": true,
        "joined_on": "2024-03-03T17:54:43.629054Z"
}
```

Instead I only get

```
{
    "id": 10,
    "email": "test17@test.com"
}
```

This is my serializer

```
from djoser.serializers import UserCreateSerializer, UserSerializer
from .models import CustomUser

class CustomUserSerializer(UserSerializer):
    class Meta(UserSerializer.Meta):
        fields = ('id', 'email', 'first_name', 'last_name', 'is_writer', 'joined_on')
        
        def get_fields(self):
            fields = super().get_fields()
            fields['email'].read_only = True
            fields['first_name'].read_only = True
            fields['last_name'].read_only = True
            fields['is_writer'].read_only = True
            fields['joined_on'].read_only = True
            return fields
        # read_only_fields = ('email', 'first_name', 'last_name', 'is_writer',)

class CustomUserCreateSerializer(UserCreateSerializer):
    class Meta(UserCreateSerializer.Meta):
        fields = ('email', 'password', 'first_name', 'last_name', 'is_writer', 'joined_on')
        extra_kwargs = {
            'last_name': {'required': False, 'allow_null': True},
        }
```

In my settings file I have added these

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [

    #DJANGO PRE-DEFINED APPS
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',

    #APPS
    'account',

    #3RD PARTY LIBRARIES
    'rest_framework',
    'djoser',
]
.....
......
......
AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'account.CustomUser'

REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    'DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES': (
        'rest_framework_simplejwt.authentication.JWTAuthentication',
    )
}

SIMPLE_JWT = {
   'AUTH_HEADER_TYPES': ('JWT',),
   'ACCESS_TOKEN_LIFETIME' : timedelta(hours=3),
}

DJOSER={
    'SERIALIZERS': {
        'user':'account.serializers.CustomUserSerializer',
        'user_create': 'account.serializers.CustomUserCreateSerializer',
    }
}
```

Nothing seems to work. Is there any way to do it?
I need to integrate it with React, so having an endpoint that could give me the details of the logged-in user would be handy.
I need help with this. If somebody can help me out here, it would be nice.